# Need help for facebook fql query

Tags: python, django, facebook

I wanted to know why is this code wrong.

```
new_query = "SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE (uid=%s % request.facebook.uid) AND  time > someval.time"
new_result = request.facebook.fql.query(new_query)
```

Someval.time is correct time format according to facebook time format.
So why does it gives me wrong code??

```
new_query = "SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE (uid=%s % request.facebook.uid)
```

gives me correct value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
new_query = "SELECT ... AND  time > %s" % someval.time
```

or similar?

**Edit**:

You've posted several pieces of code that look like this:

```
"Select something WHERE x=%s % something"
```

with the percent operator and its argument both within the quotes.  You need to do something like this:

```
new_query = "SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE (uid=%s) AND (time>%s)" % \
            (request.facebook.uid, someval.time)
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. And yeah I mean above query.
new_query = "SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE uid=%s % request.facebook.uid AND  time > %s" % someval.time

Comment: The code in your comment has two %s markers but only one value passed to the % operator.  See my amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `me()` FQL shorthand to get at the user id for whom the token is issued for

`SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE uid=me()`